# Flickr API URLs not resulting in images

Tags: java, json, flickr, scribe

i have integrated the Flickr search in my java application using scribe. I am using the

```
flickr.photos.search
```

api call to get a json object as response. But after i am parsing the json object to get the url and i am testing the url . i am getting the following .gif image.
[image]

i am getting the josn response correctly then i am using this [URL FORMAT](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)
to parse the URL.
Please tell me whether this is an api problem or am i doing something wrong ??
The urls generated by me are correct since i have checked it using the flickr api explorer in the site itself.

Found my problem was not placing a .jpg at the end of the URL. So much for that..

Comment: What is the URL you triedfor the API call? How do you work with the URL? I just tried a simple [test on their page](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search), works. I also wrote a short program to show the most recent image with the tag 'sun' since I thought that maybe Java clients only get served with that gif - but that also works. (http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=28fe98d9cb8a4526027b1629372c8e6b&tags=sun&extras=url_n&per_page=10&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=94c0a743e00a21af8ae60181c5863fa5) So what do you do?

Comment: url would be nice ...